# Difference between Word2Vec and contextual embedding

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, data-science

am trying to understand the difference between word embedding and contextual embedding.

below is my understanding, please add if you find any corrections.

word embedding algorithm has a global vocabulary (dictionary) of words. when we are performing word2vec then the input corpus(unique words) maps with the global dictionary and it will return the embeddings.

contextual embedding is used to learn sequence-level semantics by considering the sequence of all words in the documents.

but I don't understand where we considered the context in a word embedding.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of contextual embeddings is correct. Contextual embeddings are generated by taking into account the context of the word in a sentence or a document. This is done by using models such as BERT, ELMO, or GPT, which are trained on large amounts of text data and can generate embeddings that capture the meaning of a word based on its context.

Regarding word embeddings, the context is not explicitly considered during training. Word embeddings are generated by looking at the co-occurrence of words in a large corpus of text. The idea behind word embeddings is that words that occur in similar contexts will have similar embeddings. For example, the word "dog" and "cat" might have similar embeddings because they often occur in similar contexts, such as "I have a pet" or "The animal is cute."

However, it's worth noting that some algorithms for generating word embeddings, such as skip-gram with negative sampling (SGNS), can be seen as implicitly taking context into account. In SGNS, the goal is to predict the context words given a target word, so the algorithm is essentially trying to learn embeddings that are good at capturing the context of a word.

Answer (score 0):

- The main difference is that, let's say if you are using word2vec embeddings then when the unknown word come then the model gets confused as it doesn't know/understands the context.
- Second thing is that, if you are using contextual embedding like wordpiece encoding, then when the new word comes then the model will try to find its embedding in its vocabulary. And if the embedding is not there, then it will break the word into subwords, and then it will try to find the embeddings for those subwords. And it will go on till the character level. And wordpiece will almost always have embeddings for the character. (Of course, to get those characters level embeddings, the wordpiece should be trained on enough data).
  For e.g. text = "My name is Harshad."
  There is high probability that there are embeddings for the words "My", "name", "is" in word2vec and wordpiece encoding. But what about the word "Harshad". The word2vec simply can't handle this word and will name is as "Unknown" word (in a way). But in wordpiece encoding the word will get divided like this: "Har##", "##shad" Now the model will look for the embedding for these 2 words. If it doesn't find them, then it will go one step forward like this: "Ha##", "##r". Now it's highly likely that there is encoding for "r" but probably not for "Ha" then it will keep looking for embeddings until it find something even on character level.
  But let's take an extreme case, let's say there is no embedding for "Harshad" then what? In this case, the model will tokenize it as "UNK". It will tell the model that, this word is not present in its vocabulary.

Comment: how non-contextual embedding(word2vec, Glove, FastText) handle the OOV (incase if it don't find in global vocabulary) ?

Answer (score 0):

Today, when talking about contextualized embeddings it is usually used to describe embeddings that dynamically change depending on the given context (for example the sentence for which the "word" appears in) and not generated once as a pre-training procedure and used as a dictionary with no dependence on the current context, like in w2v.

While both w2v and contextualized embeddings are usually generated based on the **context** that the "words" appear in, w2v is trained only once while using all of the contexts the "word" appears in as a pre-training procedure. On the other hand, contextualized embeddings are generated dynamically given "word" and the context it appears in.

An example that clearly shows the difference is the word "mouse". This word can be used to describe an animal, or a mechanical tool used to move the cursor on a computer screen. In w2v, the embedding of "mouse" will be static and will hold information about both an "animal-mouse" and "computer-mouse". In contextual embedding you will need to provide the current context the word appears in and therefore there will be a different embedding to the "mouse" in a sentece talking about animals and "mouse" in a sentence talking about computers.

Note that contextualized-embedding are talked about in the context of Large-Language-Models which can dynamically output text embeddings on the fly based on context context.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).